# Get uploaded image name

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, varien-file-uploader

I am working with the image upload,i want to get the renamed images for save into my table.

```
    original file name : t h i r d_i_m_@g e(1).jpg
    renamed file name : 1435902886t_h_i_r_d_i_m__g_e_1_.jpg(in folder)
```

### Code

```
    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($field_name);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($extension);
            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->save($path,$fname);
```

### When I print `$uploader` the result is:

```
    Varien_File_Uploader Object
    (
        [_file:protected] => Array
            (
                [name] => t h i r d_i_m_@g e(1).jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkUUDen
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 37994
            )

        [_fileMimeType:protected] => 
        [_uploadType:protected] => 0
        [_uploadedFileName:protected] => 1435904665t_h_i_r_d_i_m__g_e_1_.jpg
        [_uploadedFileDir:protected] => /home/vhosts/FederalLawyer/media/lawyer/news/image/
        [_allowCreateFolders:protected] => 1
        [_allowRenameFiles:protected] => 1
        [_enableFilesDispersion:protected] => 
        [_caseInsensitiveFilenames:protected] => 1
        [_dispretionPath:protected] => 
        [_fileExists:protected] => 1
        [_allowedExtensions:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => jpg
                [1] => png
                [2] => gif
                [3] => jpeg
            )

        [_validateCallbacks:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_result:protected] => Array
            (
                [name] => t h i r d_i_m_@g e(1).jpg
                [type] => image/jpeg
                [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkUUDen
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 37994
                [path] => /home/vhosts/FederalLawyer/media/lawyer/news/image/
                [file] => 1435904665t_h_i_r_d_i_m__g_e_1_.jpg
            )

    )
```

From this how can I get the renamed file name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a simple function, you can use to get the image name after upload the image:

```
$uploader->getUploadedFileName();
```

Comment: how to handle retrieving full relative path of image saved location ? 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100127/get-full-image-path-on-frontend-uploaded-from-custom-field-in-database

Comment: You never disappoint me. Kudos to you @Amit !

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign save value in one variable,,,like

```
$uploadresult=  $uploader->save($path,$fname);
```

And get save file like in this way

```
$saveFilename=    $uploadresult['file']
```